# Ethernet cannot connect

Tags: networking, dual-boot, ethernet

I don't have external WiFi and ethernet is my only source.

I can't copy and paste anything since I am on a MacBook at the time of writing this.

My other PC is running into this issue (Ubuntu 20 + 21). Please help! I have tried that `touch /somePlace/10-globally-managed-something.something` thingy and it still can't connect.

Will be online tomorrow at 7/8am (GMT timezone) so I'll be accepting solutions till then.

PC is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (I also tried Ubuntu 21.02 but didn't work). Ethernet is 1GB max and it worked before on Ubuntu but not now. I am also dual booting with Windows 10, Ethernet works on Windows 10.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Morning, ok will do.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work by logging in after 6 hours